# View is not returning entire model on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I created a Model, View, and Controller.  In my view, I loop through the collection of , and I create a table with each  listed, along with a Save button.

When I click the Save button, the only data returned to the controller are the ID and LandownerID -- all the other fields show as null.

I have spent most of today searching google, and trying multiple answers, none of which worked.

Controller:

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,ExemptionNumber,IssueDate,KillCount,TRAPPING,SHOOTING,DOGS,OTHER,NO_INDICATION,NOTES,SPECIES,E_LANDOWNER,EXEM_YEAR,MethodOfDisposal,NO_DATA")] ExempKillData exempKillData)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(exempKillData).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index","Owners");
            }
            return View(exempKillData);
        }
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Exemptions.Models.ExempKillData>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}



<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <table border="1" id="tbl">
        <tbody>
            ..table headers snipped...
            @foreach (var kill in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.First().ID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.First().ExemptionNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => kill.IssueDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => kill.IssueDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => kill.KillCount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => kill.KillCount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => kill.TRAPPING, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => kill.TRAPPING, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => kill.SHOOTING, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => kill.SHOOTING, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => kill.DOGS, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => kill.DOGS, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => kill.OTHER, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => kill.OTHER, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => kill.NO_INDICATION, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => kill.NO_INDICATION, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => kill.NOTES, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => kill.NOTES, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => kill.SPECIES, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => kill.SPECIES, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => kill.E_LANDOWNER, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => kill.E_LANDOWNER, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => kill.EXEM_YEAR, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => kill.EXEM_YEAR, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => kill.NO_DATA, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => kill.NO_DATA, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top" align="center">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save"  class="btn btn-default" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

}
```

Model:

```cs
    [Table("WHE.ExempKillData")]
    public partial class ExempKillData
    {
        [Display(Name ="Exemption Number")]
        public int? ExemptionNumber { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Issue Date")]
        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? IssueDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Kill Count")]
        public int? KillCount { get; set; }

        public int? TRAPPING { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
        public int? SHOOTING { get; set; }

        public int? DOGS { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
        public int? OTHER { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="No Indication")]
        public int? NO_INDICATION { get; set; }

        [StringLength(200)]
        public string NOTES { get; set; }

        [StringLength(32)]
        public string SPECIES { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="Landowner")]
        public double? E_LANDOWNER { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="Exemption Year")]
        [StringLength(4)]
        public string EXEM_YEAR { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="No Data")]
        [StringLength(40)]
        public string NO_DATA { get; set; }

        public string MethodOfDisposal { get; set; }

        public int ID { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I would expect that clicking Save would return the contents of that row back to the Controller Action, where the data could then be properly saved.

ModelState.IsValid is true for every record I try to edit, but as mentioned above, all fields except ID and E_Landowner are null.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the 'Network' tab in the inspector when you make a request? The parameters looks like below:

[image]

you can make a test on your environment right now. Inspect the element that is not binding correctly, and remove 'kill.' from its name:

[image]

When you press save, this single property should be bound correctly

The thing is, when you make 'EditorFor(model => **kill.IssueDate**), then the bolded text will be the parameter name when you make a request. So, if your model had a property of type ExempKillData, and named as 'kill', then the binding would work.

But no worries, I know what you want to do.

Just change the line

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => kill.IssueDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

to

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => kill.IssueDate, null, "IssueDate", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } });
```

the second parameter is a template which is not the one we're interested in that example, but the third one tells ASP.NET to set a different field name for that property.

I am rather dull when it comes to explaining, but I hope you got the idea :)

btw. You can remove all this 'Bind' text from method parameter. Only type and name of parameter is required

[image]

Comment: I'll give that a try when I get to the office tomorrow morning.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I changed the ExempKillData record passed from the view back to the controller to "kill," just to test out that theory.  No other changes.  Data is passing correctly, now.  Thank you, @faint220; you are a saint.

Comment: @Carthax I'm jubilant if the idea 'clicked' in your mind after reading my comment. Wishing you a lot of success in your career! cheers.